Expo project failing for iOS
I am building an app using Expo & React Native. Whenever I am building my app, I get this error while building for iOS and have not been able to resolve it after looking at multiple SO questions and GitHub issues.
I am using Expo SDK 51 and React Native 0.74.1.
Here are the logs from Expo build:
Using Expo modules
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-Core
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-RCTAppDelegate
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-menu-interface
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXManifests
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod EXUpdatesInterface
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-menu
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-jsinspector
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod RCT-Folly
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod glog
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-RCTFabric
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-Codegen
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod RCTRequired
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod RCTTypeSafety
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ReactCommon
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-NativeModulesApple
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod Yoga
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-Fabric
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-graphics
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-utils
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-featureflags
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-debug
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-ImageManager
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod React-rendererdebug
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod DoubleConversion
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod hermes-engine
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod expo-dev-launcher
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImage
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageWebPCoder
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageAVIFCoder
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod SDWebImageSVGCoder
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod libavif
error Failed to build the app: No package name found. We couldn't parse the namespace from neither your build.gradle[.kts] file at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/extra-mobile/node_modules/expo-template-bare-minimum/android/build.gradle nor your package in the AndroidManifest at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/extra-mobile/node_modules/expo-template-bare-minimum/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 783: unexpected token at ''.
 #  from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/extra-mobile/ios/Podfile:21
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # @generated end react-native-maps
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Install pods build phase for more information.

What I tried:

Deleteing node_modules and running yarn install
Downgrading to Expo SDK 50
Adding package="com.packageName" in my AndroidManifest.xml
But all that didn't help :(

All help is appreciated!

have you tried looking to see if PODS is installed?
Access iOS page and install the pods

cd ios && pod install

although i would think with Expo it should not matter

@JamieGarcia I did try pod install also which still results in the same error.

I had same problem, where it got stuck, only way was to delete PODS.
Delete the Pods directory and Podfile.lock
rm -rf Pods
rm -f Podfile.lock
Install Pods again
pod install
This should do the trick, let me know if it helped you
